# GWT Development Mode doesn't compile web application

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, compiler-construction

When I want to compile my GWT application within eclipse via "Run As -> GWT application" I get following message:

> 00:00:00,005 [WARN] Module declares a servlet class 'com.google.gwt.junit.server.JUnitHostImpl', but the web.xml has no corresponding declaration; please add the following lines to your web.xml:

```
<servlet> <servlet-name>jUnitHostImpl</servlet-name> <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.junit.server.JUnitHostImpl</servlet-class> </servlet> <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>jUnitHostImpl</servlet-name> <url-pattern>/AdminInterface/junithost/*</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>
```

When I add those lines to my web.xml the message doesn't occur anymore, but the compiler seems to be frozen. Usually there would appear a link at "Startup URL" at the top of the window, which would lead me to my web application's page. But it says "computing" all the time and the process itself doesn't use any CPU time.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this message is that you have a `*.gwt.xml` that `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.junit.JUnit" />`. There's no reason to ever include that module directly, it'll be automatically added when you run your `GWTTestCase`s.

The gwt-maven-plugin archetype is known to include such a module though (one of the many reasons I discourage using that archetype).

Remove the offending `<inherits>` and try again (and don't add the suggested servlet to your web.xml).

Answer (score 1):

> When I want to compile my GWT application within eclipse via "Run As -> GWT application" I get following message

You are actually not compiling you are running...

You have to compile the project by using the blue icon as shown in the image. As of now you are running.

[image]

In that list you can select the `GWT COMPILE PROJECT`(red icon) and you have to select your yourProjectName.gwt.xml.

Then it will start `compiling`.

About `frozen` the browser issue.

I think this frozen issue happening after you click  on the generated url. When you click on the link the application launches in your default browser.

If you compile it won't generate any URL and a message should come in Eclipse console that "`Compile Succeeded`".
Actually  the GWT application launching in the browser at that time is in development mode.