# GWT compiler doesn't notice changes in code

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, maven, compiler-construction

I use the GWT plugin for eclipse on a project, that's imported from maven. For some reason changes within my code aren't considered while compiling my web application. If I start the preview mode within eclipse, the changes are shown, but when I compile the application via console: `mvn clean gae:run -DskipTests`(this is the only way I can run my application, since the GWT Development Mode does't work - [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731663/gwt-development-mode-doesnt-compile-web-application) ), I still get some older version of my web application, which doesn't contain my changes. I already cleared my browser's cache and rebuild my eclipse project, but still no effect.

Does anyone know how to get the compiler to consider my changes?

Comment: Have you clean your project ??

Comment: Do you have the correct address with querystring gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:999?

Comment: try mvn gwt:clean gae:run

Comment: Yes, I have cleaned the entire project within eclipse and I tried the "mvn clean gae:run" and "mvn gwt:clean gae:run" commands. Didn't work.

@Sam:
Where do I find this setting?

Comment: when you start your page. you should see something like that in your url: http://127.0.0.1:8888/youpage.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Comment: when I start the server via console my page is accessible at localhost:8080.