# ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.junit.server.JUnitHostImpl

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

How do I get rid of this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.junit.server.JUnitHostImpl
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
[ERROR]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
[ERROR]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:213)
```

I've tried:

- `mvn clean`
- Eclipse project clean

But still the error is there.

Comment: Your missing a jar containing `com.google.gwt.junit.server.JUnitHostImpl`

Comment: There's not enough information in the question. Can you include the pom.xml and also say which Maven goal(s) you were trying to execute?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the problem was with the `maven-war-plugin` plugin:

```
         <plugin>
            <!-- Copies static web files from src/main/webapp to target/${webappDirectory} -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <!-- the exploded goal gets executed during compile phase -->
                  <phase>compile</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>exploded</goal>
<!--                      <goal>war</goal> -->
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                <!-- Exclude GWT client local classes from the deployment, lest
                classpath scanners such as Hibernate and Weld get confused when the webapp 
                is bootstrapping. -->
                <packagingExcludes>**/javax/**/*.*,**/client/local/**/*.class</packagingExcludes>
                <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</warSourceExcludes>             
                <!-- the exploded war structure ends up in target/${webappDirectory} -->
                <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
```

Where I copied this configuration from here:

https://github.com/errai/errai/blob/master/errai-jpa/demos/errai-jpa-demo-todo-list/pom.xml

As a supposed fix for running my Errai application in CapeDwarf environment.

Comment: For this answer to be useful to others, you'll have to at least say what you changed from the default, and why.

Comment: I agree with @JonathanFuerth. It would be very helpful if you would call out what was changed.

Answer (score 1):

I removed:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.junit.JUnit'/>
```

From my *.gwt.xml and

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jUnitHostImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.junit.server.JUnitHostImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jUnitHostImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyProject/junithost/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

from my web.xml to fix this, as recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14732962/1313268).